# Button link stopped working after I added CSS

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, youtube

I added special styling to one of my buttons, and now I can click the button but it doesn't go to the link (It's supposed to direct you to a YouTube video in a separate tab).

```css
#help {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 45px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#help:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: grey;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contact {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="help" href="https://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0" target="blank">Get help from a low-paid professional</button>
```

Notice that when you click the button, it knows that it has been clicked, based on the rectangle that forms around it, but the link just doesn't work.

I'm still a novice at this kind of stuff, so be patient with me, I might not understand what you're trying to say the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have href attribute in button. It's in a tag. Just change the button to a tag.

Following line should work:

```
<a id="help" href="https://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0" target="_blank">Get help from a low-paid professional</a>
```

If you want to use button instead of a tag. Following line should work:

```
<button id="help" onclick="window.open('https://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0')">Get help from a low-paid professional</button>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work.If I'm getting it correctly, you want me to replace the `<button>` tags with `<a>`? If so, that removes the entire purpose of all the button styling.

Comment: It's working. Following is the demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/a9fnp43h/6/

Comment: Ahh, now it seems to be working. Just wondering, shouldn't removing the button tag make it not appear as a button?

Comment: For just button use onclick=" window.open(url);".

Comment: Though, with the button you have to remove the borders explicitly.